# Rounding values > 1000 to have "K" suffix R venn diagram

Tags: r, venn-diagram

Here is my code:

```
library(VennDiagram)

# Generate 3 sets of 10000 words
set.seed(1)
set1 <- paste('word_',sample(c(1:100000) , 10000))
set.seed(2)
set2 <- paste('word_',sample(c(1:100000) , 10000))
set.seed(3)
set3 <- paste('word_',sample(c(1:100000) , 10000))

# Chart
p <- venn.diagram(
  x = list(set1, set2, set3),
  category.names = c("Set 1" , "Set 2 " , "Set 3"),
  filename = NULL
)

grid.newpage()
grid.draw(p)
dev.off()
```

In the labels for numbers I hope to round off values greater than 1000 to have the "K" prefix, eg 8043 -> 8K

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be an option to achieve this within the function. However, since it returns a `gList`, we can reach into the result and modify the text labels in place:

```r
p <- venn.diagram(
  x = list(set1, set2, set3),
  category.names = c("Set 1" , "Set 2 " , "Set 3")
)

p <- do.call(grid::gList, lapply(p, function(x) {
  if(is.null(x$label)) return(x)
  if(is.na(suppressWarnings(as.numeric(x$label)))) return(x)
  val <- as.numeric(x$label)
  if(val < 1000) return(x)
  x$label <- paste0(floor(val / 1000), "K")
  x
}))

grid.newpage()
grid.draw(p)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-09-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>